# How to click on a element through Selenium Python

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm trying to fetch data for facebook account using selenium browser python but can't able to find the which element I can look out for clicking on an export button.

See attached screenshot[image]

I tried but it seems giving me an error for the class.

```
def login_facebook(self, username, password):
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    preference = {"download.default_directory": self.section_value[24]}

    chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", preference)
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(self.section_value[20], chrome_options=chrome_options)
    self.driver.get(self.section_value[25])

    username_field = self.driver.find_element_by_id("email")
    password_field = self.driver.find_element_by_id("pass")

    username_field.send_keys(username)
    self.driver.implicitly_wait(10)

    password_field.send_keys(password)
    self.driver.implicitly_wait(10)

    self.driver.find_element_by_id("loginbutton").click()
    self.driver.implicitly_wait(10)

    self.driver.get("https://business.facebook.com/select/?next=https%3A%2F%2Fbusiness.facebook.com%2F")
    self.driver.get("https://business.facebook.com/home/accounts?business_id=698597566882728")
    self.driver.get("https://business.facebook.com/adsmanager/reporting/view?act="
                    "717590098609803&business_id=698597566882728&selected_report_id=23843123660810666")
    # self.driver.get("https://business.facebook.com/adsmanager/manage/campaigns?act=717590098609803&business_id"
    #                 "=698597566882728&tool=MANAGE_ADS&date={}-{}_{}%2Clast_month".format(self.last_month,
    #                                                                                      self.first_day_month,
    #                                                                                      self.last_day_month))

    self.driver.find_element_by_id("export_button").click()
    self.driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    self.driver.find_element_by_class_name("_43rl").click()
    self.driver.implicitly_wait(10)
```

Can you please let me know how can i click on Export button?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35531069/find-submit-button-in-selenium-without-id

Comment: Have you tried searching by the text "export" ?

Comment: @QHarr is this a way to use a text "self.driver.find_elements_by_link_text("Export").click()"

Comment: Seems still getting error, Can't able to identify a way to find the right associated class or something else :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The element with text as **Export** is a dynamically generated element so to locate the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.layerConfirm>div[data-hover='tooltip'][data-tooltip-display='overflow']"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(@class, 'layerConfirm')]/div[@data-hover='tooltip' and text()='Export']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 4):

Well, I'm able to resolve it by using xpath.
Here is the solution

```
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@class, '_271k _271m _1qjd layerConfirm')]").click()
```

Answer (score -4):

to run automation scripts on applications like facebook,  youtube quite a hard because they are huge coporations and their web applications are developed by the worlds best developers but its not impossible to run automation scripts sometimes elements are generated dynamically sometimes hidden or inactive you cant just go and click

one solution is you can do by click action by xpath realtive or absolute their is not id specified as "export_button" in resource file i think this might help you

you can also find element by class name or css selector as i see in screen shot the class name is present "_271K _271m _1qjd layerConfirm " you can perform click action on that

Comment: export_button is associated with the different button as you can see in my code.